# Waiting for reverseGeocodeCoordinate Result

Tags: swift, google-geocoder

I have a tableview in which it loads data. Once a cell is clicked on the tableview, it will open a detailed screen of the data, which contains the reversegeocoded address from the lat/lon position.

I am doing this using:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(data[indexSelected].coordinate, completionHandler: { (response, error) in
        if let address = response?.firstResult(){
            currentAddress = "\(address.thoroughfare!), \(address.locality!), \(address.country!)"
            print("Address: \(currentAddress)")
        }
    })

    <set label text to current address>
}
```

But the problem I am having is that it does not complete the reverseGeocode before opening the detailed viewcontroller.

I would like to know how I can implement a completion handler or wait for the geocode to complete when moving to the next screen.

Comment: I think you should choose from two scenarios: 1 it's to go to the next screen and use the loader until you get the data into the callback 2 You have to get the finished data with the backend so you do not have to use reverseGeocodeCoordinate.

Comment: You need to move the "<set label text to current address>" to inside the completion handler.